# Finding the temperature of the glass envelope in an incandescent light bulb

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, convection

I've been trying to evaluate the temperature of an incandescent light bulb, using radiation for the filament and convection for the bulb, the radiation's equation works fine, but the problem is the convection, here are the calculations.

$Tf = Ti + \frac{Q}{Hc*4*\pi*r^2} 
$

In which $Ti = 3000K$, $Hc = 0.016\frac{W}{K*m^2}$, $r = 0.026m$ and $Q = -4500\frac{W}{m^2}$

The equation was found using the heat transfer version of Newton's law of cooling. The Q(Heat transfer) was found dividing the wattage by the bulb area, and Hc is the heat transfer coefficient, found for Argon.

But the result is far distant from the reality, so any help in these miscalculations will be welcome.

Comment: The title and question should make it clear that you're trying to find the temperature of the glass envelope of the bulb, not the filament. Also, you should explain how you got your equation. It doesn't make sense because the units don't agree for all the terms. On the left side you have a quantity that has the units of temperature (K), but the last term on the right side has units of $1/m^2$, not K.

Comment: I'm sorry, not used to posting here, i made some adjustments, if there's anything else that needs changing, please let me know.

Comment: Units still don't work out. Your last term has the units of $(W/m^2)/((W/(K m^2) m^2) = K/m^2$, whereas it should have the units of K. Also, why is Q = -4500 $W/m^2$? Did you already take the wattage of the bulb and divide by the surface area of the glass bulb to get Q? If so, then the $4\pi r^2$ in the denominator of the last term of your equation should not be there because you've already taken that surface area into account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vacuum in most bulbs under 25 watts. This is because heat transfer by convection becomes close to 25 percent of power loss. Above 25 watts, it decreases to about 7 percent for high wattage bulbs. This can be found by found in the text,”The scientific basis of illuminating engineering by Parry Moon. That is why they have an inert gas above 25 watts and to slow evaporation of the the tungsten filament. Of course you are free to make statements you can’t back up.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick way to approximately find the temperature of the glass bulb of a $60$-watt incandescent light bulb.

The filament is a black body. The glass bulb is an effective blackbody that absorbs, $a = 0.05$ of the radiation that falls on it. There is no convection inside the bulb; inside the bulb is a vacuum. Assume no conduction through the filament leads.

So the radiative power of the filament is $P_{f}$, and the absorbed radiated power on the glass is $P_{g} = a \cdot P_{f}$.

The temperature of the filament is $2780 ~ K$. The filament length is $0.445 ~ m$ and has a radius of $22.3$ microns. The surface area is $A_{f} = 6.255 \cdot 10^{-5} ~ m^{2}$. The bulb diameter is $60 ~ mm$. The surface area of a spherical bulb is $A_{b} = 0.0113 ~ m^{2}$. The radiative power equation between the filament and the glass bulb is:

$$ a \cdot P_{f} = P_{g} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

$$ a \cdot A_{f} \cdot T_{f}^{4} = A_{g} \cdot T_{g}^{4} \tag{2} \label{2} $$

$$ T_{g} = \left[ T_{f}^{4} \cdot \frac{a \cdot A_{f}}{A_{g}} \right]^{0.25} = 358 ~ K = 185 ~ F \tag{3} \label{3} $$

Comment: (1) There is no vacuum in most light bulbs, but argon gas. (2) The transport from the glass to the surroundings will be dominated by convection – your equations assume that the heat loss of the glass is only due to radiation.